# Filter least cloudy image per each tile in GEE

Tags: sentinel-2, google-earth-engine

Is there a “quick" way in Google Earth Engine to show in an image collection (Sentinel 2) the least cloudy image per each path/row or tile (multiple tiles) for a given timeframe? So far I managed to filter but not to pick the selection of the best images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can sort() and mosaic():

```js
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');

var composite = s2.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
                  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false)
                  .map(function(image) {
                    return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));
                  })
                  .mosaic();
```

Since there's a time band, you'll be able to recover the date of each pixel.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas! How can I include in your code a command to filter by one specific region (country). I tried with .filterBounds but I got some error...

Comment: To do it for a country, s2 = s2.filterBounds(geometry).

Answer (score 3):

Sentinel-2 uses MGRS tiles (granules) as described on the [Sentinel-2 Data Products](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products) page.

Approach:

1. Filter the collection by date range and MGRS tile
2. Sort using the Sentinel-2 image's `CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE` property
3. Extract the first image in the sorted collection

In code:

```js
var START_DATE = '2017-02-15';
var END_DATE = '2017-04-15';
var MGRS_TILE = '31RCL';

var s2_unsorted = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                    .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', MGRS_TILE)
                    .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE);
var s2_sorted = s2_unsorted.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE');
var least_cloudy_image = ee.Image(s2_sorted.first());

Map.centerObject(least_cloudy_image);
Map.addLayer(
  least_cloudy_image,
  {bands:'B4,B3,B2', min:0, max:3000},
  'least cloudy image'
);    
print('least cloudy image', least_cloudy_image);
```

It can be useful to print out the image collection, and the list of metadata properties to confirm that it is working the way you expect:

```js
var MAX_IMAGES_IN_LIST = 100;
var getCloudMetadata = function (coll) {
  return coll.toList(MAX_IMAGES_IN_LIST).map(
    function (i) {
      return ee.Image(i).get('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE');
    }
  );
};

print(
  'START_DATE', START_DATE,
  'END_DATE', END_DATE,
  'MGRS_TILE', MGRS_TILE
);
print(
  's2 (unsorted)', s2_unsorted,
  'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE metadata', getCloudMetadata(s2_unsorted)
);
print(
  's2 (sorted)', s2_sorted,
  'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE metadata', getCloudMetadata(s2_sorted)
);
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler! I don't want sort for just one tile, my goal is to sort for each tile of a region, for instances, a country: var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw').
  filter(ee.Filter.inList("Country", ["Mozambique"])); But I'm not being able to do that... Mozambique is huge,I don't want to spend time sort tile by tile :)

Comment: @Tyler Erickson- I am having the same problem where I want the least cloud image from the Sentinel 2 image collection across entire ROI, that has multiple tiles. Were you able to find a solution?